# Use vector pattern to cut pattern into mesh

Tags: mesh, vector

I’m trying to find a way to cut or extrude vector patterns into an existing mesh.

Example- imprint pattern against curved mesh then extrude pattern - it however needs to follow the shap of the original mesh

Comment: I'm still not sure what you want to do exactly.  Could you create a visual example in blender or gimp?   A 'Vector Pattern' is ambiguous, do you have a mathematical vector field?

Comment: By "vector pattern" do you mean a curve? If so, you might have some success using a _shrinkwrap_ modifier.

Comment: Maybe what you're looking of is the Knife Project tool?

Comment: .svg image of a company logo as example. Essentially import .svg image, place it directly against the mesh and somehow engrave or extrude the logo into mesh.